# Bianchi 2nd hand bike information

Tags: road-bike, identify-this-bike

I bought this bike 2nd hand and I would like to find out more information about it, but cannot find it in the Bianchi catalogues. Might someone be able to give me some guidance? I know it is a Bianchi Forza made in the 1990s.

[image: Top of the downtube showing the Shimano-branded downtube shifters]
[image: Front of head tube showing "Bianchi" eagle crest head badge]
[image: Left side view of bicycle, showing "Bianchi" on the downtube and "Forza" on the top tube]
[image: Front of the seat tube, showing a "B" logo with "Superset II" across it and "Chrome-Moly" "Double butted" below]

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles!  Did you intend to include a photo with your question?  Please do include one or several photos, otherwise we have very little to work with.

Comment: Many thanks, I had done it.

Comment: Nice bike, that

Comment: That's no Bianchi, it's not Celeste Green! (I kid... I kid... kinda...)

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be a [1991 Bianchi Forza](https://cdn.shoplightspeed.com/shops/650207/files/48075688/img-6824-2.jpg) (from the [1991 catalogue](https://www.gringineer.com/blogs/gringineer-cycles-bike-blog/1991-bianchi-catalog/)).  The logo changed the following year, and the colour has changed from the 1990 model.

[image: 1991 Bianchi Forza with specs]

You can compare the [1990 model](https://cdn.shoplightspeed.com/shops/650207/files/48074859/img-6803-2.jpg) (from the [1990 catalogue](https://www.gringineer.com/blogs/gringineer-cycles-bike-blog/1990-bianchi-catalog/)) and the [1992 model](https://cdn.shoplightspeed.com/shops/650207/files/48076634/img-6850-1.jpg) (from the [1992 catalogue](https://www.gringineer.com/blogs/gringineer-cycles-bike-blog/1992-bianchi-catalog/)).

Answer (score 3):

Based on your paint scheme and decals I think the 1991 is the best match.

There was [no Forza in 1989](https://www.gringineer.com/blogs/gringineer-cycles-bike-blog/1989-bianchi-catalog/)

[Forza in 1990](https://www.gringineer.com/blogs/gringineer-cycles-bike-blog/1990-bianchi-catalog/)
[image]
[image]
[image]
Made in red or Sierra blue - no two color scheme

[Forza in 1991](https://www.gringineer.com/blogs/gringineer-cycles-bike-blog/1991-bianchi-catalog/)
[image]
Made in Aqua or Black/Slate
I believe the Black/Slate bike is pictured and it looks very much like the bike in question. The decals seem a little off but it's hard to tell.
I think this one is the best match.

[Forza in 1992](https://www.gringineer.com/blogs/gringineer-cycles-bike-blog/1992-bianchi-catalog/)
[image]

For 1993 all I could find is what I think is a [Japanese catalog](http://labibleduvelocataloguesbianchi.blogspot.com/p/bianchi-1993.html) - no Forza and the scan is so bad it's hard to make out details.

Comment: Great ! It is exactly the 91's . Thanks soo much. Today I  had ride for the first time and this chromoloy frame is very confortable  and it is a pleasure to guide her.